# Component rerendering with Expo video-av

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am curious about something I am seeing with a mobile app I am building. Currently, I am using Expo's video-av import to showcase an mp4 file when the user initially opens the app. From here, they would either have the option to sign in, sign in with google or sign up for a new account.

Here is the behavior I am seeing: The component that has the video in it continues to rerender over and over as long as the video is playing. When I enable native controls again so that I can pause it, I notice the rerendering stops.

Im curious, is this expected behavior? Initially, I feel like maybe the answer is yes because its constantly playing and therefore the component is being told to rerender, however I am wondering if there is another or better way I should be handling this in my application. Here is the code below for reference (Ignore the borderWidth: 1. Its just so I can partition flex and see where my sections are while building):

```
import { View, StyleSheet, Button } from "react-native";
import { Video, ResizeMode } from "expo-av";
import { Text } from "react-native";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function WelcomeScreen() {
  const video = useRef(null);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState({});
  const [isVideoLoaded, setIsVideoLoaded] = useState();
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Video
        ref={video}
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          alignSelf: "stretch",
        }}
        source={require("../../assets/video/nature-walk.mp4")}
        useNativeControls={false}
        resizeMode="cover"
        isLooping
        shouldPlay={true}
        onPlaybackStatusUpdate={setStatus}
        onLoadStart={() => setIsVideoLoaded(false)}
        onReadyForDisplay={() => setIsVideoLoaded(true)}
      />
      {isVideoLoaded === true && (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            position: "absolute",
            top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0
          }}
        >
          <View style={{flex: 1, borderWidth: 1}}/>
          <View style={{flex: 2, borderWidth: 1}}>
            <View style={{justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'flex-start', paddingLeft: 24, paddingBottom: 24}}>
              <Text style={{fontFamily: 'open-sans-bold', color: 'white', fontSize: 28}}>sample</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={{justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'flex-start', paddingLeft: 24}}>
              <Text style={{fontFamily: 'open-sans-bold', color: 'white', fontSize: 28}}>sample</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
            <View style={{flex: 1, borderWidth: 1}}>
            </View>
          
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
  },
  video: {
    alignSelf: "center",
    width: 320,
    height: 200,
  },
  buttons: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});
```

I have tried using useCallback inside of a useEffect but that doesnt seem to be helping. I threw console logs into this component and I can see them continuously being logged while the video is running